# Subdomain on VPS not working

Tags: apache-2.4, vps, subdomain, ubuntu-16.04

I am running my site on my VPS. Let's call it example.com. I want to add a subdomain, sub.example.com. I've added an A-record, created the folder /var/www/sub and added the VirtualHost part. My config file in /apache2/sites-available now looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub/

    <Directory /var/www/sub>
        Allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. Whenever I browse to this subdomain I get redirected to the main site. It seems like apache doesn't redirect me to the subfolder and its contents. How can I get this to work?

Oh, here's the output of `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost sub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:36)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton added the problem in my main post, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by applying the settings to the config file for port 443 as well. I totally forgot to mention this (and the config file itself too).

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ServerAlias www.sub.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```